# Passing Data to an Activity without Starting the Receiving Activity (Android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, android-intent

I am making a contacts app that presents the user with the following Buttons, "Create New Contact", "Edit Contact", "Delete Contact", "Display Contact" and "Finish".

There is a Contacts List activity which must be entered/displayed when clicking on Edit, Delete, or Display. **When creating a contact in the "Create New Contact" Activity, I would like to send the Contact object (it implements Parcelable) to an ArrayList within the Contacts List Activity WITHOUT starting it, once the Contact is added, I would like to return to MainActivity.**

**I am unsure how to go about this as using Intents results in going straight to the activity and I am also unsure how to cause the ArrayList within the Contacts List Activity to save.**

Any suggestions? I do not need exact code but I am unsure what direction to go in to accomplish this task.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you really want to achieve. can it be helped with intent.putExtra(STR, STR) ?? so that you can save the data into intent without starting the activity.

Comment: It would be - intent.putExtra(STR KEY, Contact Object).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the data model should live in the context of the app and not in the context of an activity. Then the data is accessible from all activities. Now the only object you need to pass by intent is the id of a data set.

This general principle also enables what you want to do, start a new activity, do some data manipulation and send a new intend to the next activity without displaying the previous one at all.

Answer (score -1):

There is a logical problem: if there is not a `Activity` instance, why do you need to send data to **it**(even not existed)?

Alternatively, if you'd like the data existed within the whole user lifecycle, it needs to save edited data(ADD,EDIT,REMOVE) in somewhere like local storage or Database. And fetch data(then parse it to specific object) from persistent layer when start the presenter activity (where received data and presented them to user).